# Update property file from response via groovy in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is it possible to update property file straightway through groovy script according to response xml that receive from SoapUI?

I tried following steps

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport


def responseAsXml = context.expand( '${Simple Search - Request 1#ResponseAsXml}')
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseAsXml);


def formataddress = holder.getNodeValues("//result//formatted_address");


props = new java.util.Properties();
props.load( new FileInputStream('testProps.properties') );


def  sQA_PROP_LOCATION = props.getProperty('QA_PROP_LOCATION');
```

Basically I need to update `QA_PROP_LOCATION` property value in the `abc.property` file with `formatted_address` node value in response xml

Response XML as Follows

```
<GeocodeResponse>
   <status>OK</status>
   <result>
      <type>locality</type>
      <type>political</type>
      <formatted_address>Rio de Janeiro, Brazil</formatted_address>
      <address_component>
         <long_name>Rio de Janeiro</long_name>
         <short_name>Rio de Janeiro</short_name>
         <type>locality</type>
         <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <address_component>
............
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi, it's not pretty clear why you are trying to change 'abc.property'. If you want define different values for the same property I would suggest create project (or TestSuite) property and update it like described in http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html

Comment: My intention was to update maintain properties (any level) as a separate file rather than within SoapUI (where you mentioned above)

Comment: what is problem being faced. Looks you need to set the property value and write it into file.